# Why isn't working the shake effect on the MUI dialog when clicking away?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add a shake effect when the user clicks away outside the MUI dialog so that he/she knows that click away isn't allowed.

So far this is the code but it isn't working as the effect isn't applied to the dialog when clicking away. So I'm pretty lost, why is not showing the effect? Thanks for your contributions. I'm new to react and MUI.

```
export const StatusModalFail = (): ReactElement => {
  const shakeAnimation = keyframes`
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
  `;
  
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const CustomBackdrop = (props) => {
    const handleClick = (event) => {
      const dialogElement = document.getElementById('custom-dialog');
      if (dialogElement) {
        dialogElement.style.animation = `${shakeAnimation} 0.5s linear`;
        setTimeout(() => {
          dialogElement.style.animation = '';
        }, 500);
      }
      event.stopPropagation();
    };
    return <Backdrop {...props} onClick={handleClick} />;
  };

 
  const handleCloseButton = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
      aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      id="custom-dialog"
      open={open}
      PaperProps={{
           sx: {
            width: '100%',
            maxWidth: '500px!important',
            height: '100%',
            maxHeight: '250px!important',
          },
      }}
      BackdropComponent={CustomBackdrop}
      disableEscapeKeyDown
    >
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <CrossIcon
          style={{
            color: '#fa6757',
            width: 48,
            height: 48,
            padding: 8,
          }}
        />
      </Box>
      <DialogTitle
        id="alert-dialog-title"
        sx={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          alignContent:'center',
          paddingTop: '2px',
          textAlign: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <Typography variant="buttons.default">couldn't saved</Typography>
      </DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent sx={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          alignContent:'center',
          paddingTop: '2px',
          textAlign: 'center',
      }}
      >
        <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
          <Typography color="textSecondary" variant="body.default">
            try again later
          </Typography>
          <DialogActions sx={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          alignContent:'center',
          paddingTop: '2px',
          textAlign: 'center',
          }}
          >
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              sx={{
              width: 350,
              height: 50,
              marginTop: 4,
              fontSize: 16,
              }}
              onClick={handleCloseButton}
            >
              close
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </DialogContentText>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
    );
};
```

Comment: Never ever create component inside another component if you don't know what are you doing. Not everything should be inside component. If it is required to be there, you have to use useCallback. Try moving CustomBackdrop and everything it uses outside of StatusModalFail component

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can use the useCallback in my code? I'm new in react and a bit lost.

Comment: There is a react documentation, you can check it out. That case you don't need it. Just move CustomBackdrop outside of StatusModalFail

Comment: Just move outside, if you prefer it can be in different file

Comment: But although putting the CustomBackdrop  in a new file and call it from StatusModalFail, the shake effect isn't applied. any other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom Backdrop, just add a state and use the [`onClose`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog/#props) with `reason: "backdropClick"` to update it when the `Backdrop` is clicked and add your animation to the [`.MuiDialog-container` class](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog/#css):

```
import { ReactElement, useState } from "react";
import { keyframes, styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CrossIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';

const shakeAnimation = keyframes`
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
  `;

const StyledDialog = styled(Dialog, {
  shouldForwardProp: prop => prop !== 'backdropClicked'
})<{
  backdropClicked: boolean
}>(({ backdropClicked, }) => ({
  ...backdropClicked && {
    '& .MuiDialog-container': {
      animation: `${shakeAnimation} 0.5s linear`
    }
  }
}))

export const StatusModalFail = (): ReactElement => {
  
  
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [backdropClicked, setBackdropClicked] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = (event: {}, reason: "backdropClick" | "escapeKeyDown") => {

    if(reason === 'backdropClick') {
      setBackdropClicked(true);

      setTimeout(() => {
        setBackdropClicked(false);
      }, 500);
    }
  }

 
  const handleCloseButton = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Open modal</Button>
      <StyledDialog
        backdropClicked={backdropClicked}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        id="custom-dialog"
        open={open}
        PaperProps={{
            sx: {
              width: '100%',
              maxWidth: '500px!important',
              height: '100%',
              maxHeight: '250px!important',
            },
        }}
        onClose={handleClose}
        disableEscapeKeyDown
      >
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <CrossIcon
            style={{
              color: '#fa6757',
              width: 48,
              height: 48,
              padding: 8,
            }}
          />
        </Box>
        <DialogTitle
          id="alert-dialog-title"
          sx={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignContent:'center',
            paddingTop: '2px',
            textAlign: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Typography variant="button">couldn't saved</Typography>
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent sx={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignContent:'center',
            paddingTop: '2px',
            textAlign: 'center',
        }}
        >
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            <Typography color="textSecondary" variant="body1">
              try again later
            </Typography>
            <DialogActions sx={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignContent:'center',
            paddingTop: '2px',
            textAlign: 'center',
            }}
            >
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                sx={{
                width: 350,
                height: 50,
                marginTop: 4,
                fontSize: 16,
                }}
                onClick={handleCloseButton}
              >
                close
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
      </StyledDialog>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit goofy-james-8yn835]

Comment: Thanks you sooo much, now the dialog shakes when clicking away!!!!